# How do I fix an "ERROR_PROXY_GATEWAY" error while deploying with Azure App Service deployment in combination with -useCHECKSUM

Tags: msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have setup a self hosted release agent for releasing my software to an Isolated App Service. If I deploy this using the Azure App Service deployment task (V4), this works just fine. I want to use the -useCHECKSUM option but this breaks the release. I get an error stating: "Error: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."

I have tried google-ing for the error but I could not find any relation between the parameter and the Error. I suspect the -useCHECKSUM is using a different route to deploy the Application but I cannot find out what it is using.

More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxxxxxx") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"). This can happen if a proxy server is interrupting communication with the destination server. Disable the proxy server and try again.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_PROXY_GATEWAY.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
Error count: 1.

2019-07-31T08:38:16.5670711Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-07-31T08:38:16.5680985Z ##[error]Error: Error Code: ERROR_PROXY_GATEWAY

Comment: It just add -useCHECKSUM argument to msdeploy.exe and will compare files in server, then just update modified files. What's the result if you call MSDeploy.exe to deploy package to azure app service? (detail command can be found in log). You may try to create a new app service, then try again.

Comment: Got this error as well after adding -useChecksum parameter. Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: I am also having this problem, did you discover an resolution?